# Can a nonlinear dynamical system be rewritten in terms of constraints?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-topology, dynamical-systems, control-theory, optimal-control

My question is based on thoughts after reading to a specific section in the paper ["On Contraction Analysis for Nonlinear Systems"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0005109898000193) by W. Lohmiller and JJ. Slotine, **Section 4.2 Constrained Systems**. Those interested in answering my question should probably read this section first.

**Question**

> Suppose I have an $n$ dimensional nonlinear dynamical system 
>   $$x'(t)=f(x) \quad x\in \mathbb{R}^n $$
>   with converges to a $m$-dimensional submanifold $\mathcal{M}=\{x:g(x)=0\}$ for any initial condition ($\mathcal{M}$ is not invariant for all $t$, but all attracting invariant subsets and equilibrium points of the system are in $\mathcal{M}$. I am mentioning this specifically because the background I have I read on constrained systems assumes $\mathcal{M}$ is invariant which is not the case here). Can I rewrite the system in terms of $n-1$ dimensional ODE with a constraint, such that the ode system has the same dynamics, is of the form of Section 4.2? That is 
>   $$z'=\underbrace{f(z)}_{\text{constrained dynamics $z=g(x)$}}+\underbrace{n}_{\text{Superimposed flow normal to the manifold}} $$

**Background to my question**

After reading a [review on numerical methods for Lypunov functions](http://sro.sussex.ac.uk/id/eprint/56983/) and ["On Contraction Analysis for Nonlinear Systems"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0005109898000193) I am in love with using contraction metrics for analysis of dynamical systems as it helps me answer some complex problems (none are related directly to control theory). I have a system that has the properties specified in the question. If I could apply the results as seen in Section 4.2 to my system (separating the flow projected onto a manifold and flow normal to a manifold) that would be great.

*Why do I care about section 4.2?*

There are two reasons why I want to use the results of in the paper:

- The main result of section 4.2

  - Given a system of the form $z'=f(z)+n$ the variation of the contraction metric which governs the dynamics of the ODE system is given by $$\frac { 1 } { 2 } \frac { d } { d t } \left( \delta \mathbf { x } ^ { T } \mathbf { M } \delta \mathbf { x } \right) = \delta \mathbf { x } ^ { T } \frac { \partial \mathbf { z }^T } { \partial \mathbf { x } } \frac { \partial \mathbf { f } } { \partial \mathbf { z } } \frac { \partial \mathbf { z } } { \partial \mathbf { x } } \delta \mathbf { x } - \delta \mathbf { x } ^ { T } \frac { \partial ^ { 2 } \mathbf { z } } { \partial \mathbf { x } ^ { 2 } } \mathbf { n } \delta \mathbf { x }$$
  - Note that $\delta x$ is a linear tangent differential form.
  - $\frac { \partial \mathbf { z }^T } { \partial \mathbf { x } } \frac { \partial \mathbf { f } } { \partial \mathbf { z } } \frac { \partial \mathbf { z } } { \partial \mathbf { x } }$ is the projection of the jacobian onto the submanifold.
- The term containg $n$ vanishes on the submanifold.
- Once you find the contraction metric $M(x)$ for a nonlinear system $x'=f(x)$ (Note for $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ $M(x)$ is an $n$ by $n$ matrix). The lypunov function of the system is given by $V(x)=f(x)^TM(x)f(x)$ ($f(x)^T$ is the transpose of the vector $f(x)$). See Section 3.7 of the paper for details. From my knowledge this is the first time a contraction metric was used this way.

**Notes:**

- If you need any clarification please comment.
- If it is possible to separate a dynamical system in terms of flow normal to a manifold and flow projected onto a manifold that would be acceptable as well, as that is essentially what I am looking for.
- I am not familiar with constrained dynamical systems. I may be missing something quite obvious. Feel free to tell me, so I can update my post as necessary.
- If there are publications that specifically expand/apply the results of Section 4.2 I would greatly appreciate any citations.
- Feel free to edit the tags of my question. I have put in the control tag given the material I have read and with the rest of the content of the paper I thought it was appropriate.
- This was originally posted on [math overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330578/can-a-nonlinear-dynamical-system-be-rewritten-in-terms-of-constraints) and I wanted to post here in case anyone could contribute.

Comment: You have your system in the coordinates $x$. You define the new coordinates, normal and projected. It seems that if the change of coordinates is invertible than you can always rewrite your system in the new ones despite the properties of the manifold $\mathcal{M}$.

However, another question is if you can apply the results from Slotine's book when the manifold is not invariant. I do not have the book at the moment. Is there any particular property that you want to use?

Comment: @Arastas Thanks for your comment. First the paper was published after both of slotine's books (in 1998 while this books were first published 1986 and 1991), and as far as I know none of the novel results are in these books.You can see a nicely typeset preprint http://web.mit.edu/nsl/www/preprints/contraction.pdf I have added a comment on why I want to use this result. The tldr is that applying the result gives a very nice formula for the contraction metric, once you have a contraction metric finding the lypunov function which governs the system is trivial.

Comment: @Arastas Also could you provide an example of your comment. "You define the new coordinates, normal and projected. It seems that if the change of coordinates is invertible than you can always rewrite your system in the new ones despite the properties of the manifold M. " I am admittedly not very familiar with some of the terminology and some guidance would be appreciated. For example I am not sure what projection to use.